# Webshpere datasource error:Unable to lookup JNDI name

Tags: oracle, hibernate, websphere, datasource, jndi

I am developing an application with Hibernate and Websphere Application Server 8.0.

I have create a datasource in Websphere and it can connect with database successfully.

But from application I am getting following error:

> SystemErr     R Error creating Session: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDS]

Following is the setup I have done:

1. Websphere datasource setup:

[image: Successfully connected with database]

2. hibernate.cfg.xml

[image: hibernate.cfg.xml]

3. web.xml

   [image: web.xml]

When I try to get sessiofactory, it gives me error:

HibernateUtil.java:

```
try
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
    catch (HibernateException he)
    {
        System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + he);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }
```

**Error:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl.getJavaNameSpace(WebComponentMetaDataImpl.java:143)
>       at com.ibm.ws.threadContext.JavaNameSpaceAccessorImpl.getJavaNameSpace(JavaNameSpaceAccessorImpl.java:79)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.createURLContextRoot(javaURLContextFactory.java:137)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextFactory.getObjectInstance(UrlContextFactory.java:101)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.URLContextProvider.getContext(URLContextProvider.java:43)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.getURLContext(DelegateContext.java:252)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.findContext(DelegateContext.java:214)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.findContext(DelegateContext.java:207)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:157)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:432)
>       at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
>       at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1818)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1776)
>       at com.test.util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:25)

Error creating Session: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDS]

Please let me know what I am missing.

I have applied more tries, now I am getting following error:

> FFDC Exception:javax.naming.NamingException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.createURLContextRoot ProbeId:142 Reporter:java.lang.Class@dfac0b43
>   javax.naming.NamingException: NMSV0308W: javaURLContextFactory cannot create a javaURLContext object because there is no java URL name space currently accessible from the executing thread.
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.createURLContextRoot(javaURLContextFactory.java:170)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextFactory.getObjectInstance(UrlContextFactory.java:101)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.URLContextProvider.getContext(URLContextProvider.java:43)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.getURLContext(DelegateContext.java:252)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.findContext(DelegateContext.java:214)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.findContext(DelegateContext.java:207)
>       at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:157)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:432)
>       at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
>       at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1818)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1776)
>       at com.test.util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:25)

Comment: From what component are you calling this? I don't see any web component like servlet or filter in the stack trace. Maybe you are calling it outside of the container.

Comment: Hello Gas, if you see the stacktrace, in last line you will find HibernateUtil.java. It is my custom file and its code is mentioned above. I am getting this error from 3rd line in try block i.e.         sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

Comment: Yes, but what calls that HibernateUtil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create binding between you reference and JNDI name?

You can do it

- either using admin console - `Enterprise Application > ApplicationName > Resource references`. then select reference and map it to the datasource JNDI name
- or using binding file - you need to create `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file with the following contents:

> `<resource-ref name="jdbc/OracleDS" binding-name="jdbc/OracleDS" />`

Comment: Yes it is there, but no effect of it at all.

Comment: May be this should be the problem, as I removed all the instances and create again with this binding, it started working. I am not 100% sure, but I think this is the thing I missed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In WebSphere you don't need `java:comp/env` at the hibernate datasource.

So your `hibernate.cfg.xml` would look like this:

```xml
.
.
.
<!-- JNDI Datasource -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/OracleDS</property>
.
.
.
```